# Upload images with preview on picture box in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]

I want to upload image in asp.net mvc like this way.I am using input type file for uploading images , its working fine but I want that when user click on this image and select that image , that image would appear on this type of box , how would I do that . I am saving images path in database and putting them on file directory.

Comment: you want a preview before you upload?

Comment: Yes I want to preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the best bet is to use the [HTML5 file API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) to read the contents of the attached image to display a preview. When the user submits the file you could do the server-side processing as you currently are, store the URL and return to the browser the location of the new image for proper preview. But check the performance of previewing a large image.

The link shows an example of previewing the file. I've copied the code in here as well, but please check the article for better understanding.

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    // Only process image files.
    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        // Render thumbnail.
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
          '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'
        ].join('');
        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
      };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```css
.thumb {
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```

Comment: This answer works, I am wondering why there is no up vote on this answer.