# How to use Picture Box in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have wrap(assign) a image to picture box control in Windows Application as follow and it works properly.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ImageGenrator generateImage = new ImageGenrator())
        {
            string ActualText = string.Empty;
            pictureBox1.Image = generateImage.DrawText(ref ActualText);

        }
    }
```

But i want to use same concept in asp.net mvc.
So, how i can i use it..What is the Picture Box control alternative in asp.net mvc

```
 pictureBox1.Image = generateImage.DrawText(ref ActualText);
```

Please help..Thanks in advance

Comment: mvc  use another concepts. it separates serverside and frontend. so you can't control (directly) through c# code the frontend. You would want to do this through a request to get the text and then using JS to draw the image in a canvas.

Comment: Thanks Alex, Can provide sample code..Please

Comment: you might want to look at this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087583/upload-images-with-preview-on-picture-box-in-asp-net-mvc